# Circle is not being applied on map marker icon

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, google-maps

This is the code I wrote

```
     val lco = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)
        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
        myGoogleMap!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lco, 15F))
        myGoogleMap!!.isMyLocationEnabled = true

        if (userLocationMarker == null) {
            markerOptions.position(lco)
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.redcar))
            markerOptions.rotation(location.bearing)
            markerOptions.anchor(0.5F, 0.5F)
            userLocationMarker = myGoogleMap!!.addMarker(markerOptions)
            myGoogleMap!!.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lco, 15F))
        } else {
            userLocationMarker!!.position = lco
            userLocationMarker!!.rotation = location.bearing
        }
        
        if (userAccuracyCircle == null) {
            val circleOptions = CircleOptions()
            circleOptions.center(lco)
            circleOptions.strokeWidth(4F)
            circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.rgb(47, 214, 17))
            circleOptions.fillColor(Color.rgb(255, 213, 0))
            circleOptions.radius(location.accuracy.toDouble())
            userAccuracyCircle = myGoogleMap!!.addCircle(circleOptions)
        } else {
            userAccuracyCircle!!.center = lco
            userAccuracyCircle!!.radius = location.accuracy.toDouble()
        }
    }
```

Hello folks, I am new to android dev and was trying to build vehicle tracking app using google map sdk. But there is an issue in my app that the circleOption is not being applied on the icon.

Comment: Probably should check if location "hasAccuracy" - it's not always available and is 0 if not  - which means the circle is not visible since its radius is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Based on feedback from @Sumit Singh comment, the issue is that not all Location data has an accuracy reading.  And so, the accuracy value (`.accuracy`) may be 0 if no accuracy is available.

From the docs of `getAccuracy`:

> This is only valid if hasAccuracy() is true.

The default value of this getter when there is no accuracy is 0.0.  (This is implementation dependent and is not specified.)

In the OP code, if there is no accuracy, the 0.0 is used here:

```
circleOptions.radius(location.accuracy.toDouble())
```

and so a circle with radius of 0.0 is not visible (although still exists).

Solution should be to use:

```
location.hasAccuracy
```

and if no accuracy either a) have no circle or b) have a default circle radius if no accuracy and a "special" color - based on your application.

Comment: this is very helpful information sir, thank you very much.